# Find $\frac{AC \times BC}{AD \times BD}$

Tags: geometry

> $AC$ is $2004$. $CD$ bisects angle $C$. If the perimeter of $ABC$ is $6012$, find $\dfrac{AC \times BC}{AD \times BD}$.

[image]
**Attempt**

Let $c = AD+BD$.
We have that $\dfrac{AC}{AD} = \dfrac{BC}{BD}$. Thus, $$\dfrac{BD}{AD}+1 = \dfrac{BC}{AC}+1 \implies \dfrac{BD+AD}{AD} = \dfrac{AC+BC}{AC} = \dfrac{c}{AD} \implies AD = \dfrac{AC \cdot c}{AC+BC}.$$ Likewise it is easy to see by the angle bisector theorem that $BD = \dfrac{BC \cdot c}{AC+BC}$. Thus, we have that $\dfrac{AC \times BC}{AD \times BD} = \dfrac{AC \times BC}{\dfrac{AC \cdot BC \cdot c^2}{(AC+BC)^2}} = \dfrac{(AC+BC)^2}{c^2} = \dfrac{(2004+BC)^2}{(4008-BC)^2}$. But this answer seems to depend on $BC$, which makes no sense as the question indicates it is constant. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of questions lately. Do note that there is a question cap of 50 per month.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not well-posed. In fact, $BC$ can be anything between $1002$ and $3006$ (not inclusive), and the quantity in question can be any number greater than $1$ and less than $25$.

Comment: By triangle inequality, we can obtain the bound of $BC<3006$.

Comment: Yes, @Element118, of course you're right.

Answer (score 0):

If instead of numerical value of $AC$, numerical value of $AB$ was given then the required expression would have a unique answer.

Let $a, b, c$ represent $BC, AC, AB$ respectively.

By,  ange bisector theorem we have, $\frac{AD}{BD}=\frac{b}{a}$.

So, $AD=\frac{bc}{a+b}$ and $\frac{ca}{a+b}$.

$\frac{AC \times BC}{AD \times BD}=\left(\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c}\right)^2=\left(\frac{2004}{c}-1 \right)^2$.

So, knowing $c$ is enough.